# jQuery if statement adding class to an inner div

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following structure:

[image]

I have managed to adjust the `#header-sticky-wrapper` div with the below code however I need to write an if statement to say if `is-sticky` is found then apply a class to the `logo heading-title` div
[

**Code:**

`$('.sticky-wrapper').addClass( 'nonHomeLogo' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may directly add a class to .logo without having an if.

```
$('#header-sticky-wrapper.is-sticky .logo').addClass('whatever-class'); // this is better
```

or

```
$('#header-sticky-wrapper.is-sticky').find('.logo').addClass('whatever-class');
```

To use if, here's the code [one way to do it]. I prefer the above code though.

```
if( $('#header-sticky-wrapper').hasClass('.is-sticky') )
    $('.logo').addClass('whatever-class');
```

Full Code:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#header-sticky-wrapper.is-sticky .logo').addClass('whatever-class');
    })
</script>
<div id="header-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper nonHomeLogo is-sticky" style="height: 205px;">
    <header id="header" class="nonHome header_v3 animated fadeInDown">
        <div class="header-main">
            <div class="header-top hidden-xs">
                <div class="wd-sticky" id="wd-sticky">
                    <div class="header-middle hidden-xs">
                        <div class="header-middle-content nonHomeContent">
                            <div class="logo heading-title">
                                <div>details</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it does not add to the .logo class

Comment: @JessMcKenzie, can you post how you called this statement $('.logo').addClass('whatever-class'); -- button click? form load?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie, not sure why it's not working for you. So, I attached my simulation /full code. It should work, unless you missed the jquery plugin or $(function(){...})

Comment: Yup not adding :( https://www.dropbox.com/s/gun72u1yivjuylk/Screenshot%202016-02-09%2019.16.22.png?dl=0

Comment: I am using jQuery v2.1.1. What version are you using?

Comment: Just a guess, I think your "header-sticky-wrapper" div is loaded at some later time (probably through ajax) such that it is no longer within the scope of jquery.ready(). You have to debug it. I suggest that you create a button click to addClass() manually. You may want to try it.

Comment: When loaded `#header-sticky-wrapper` is loaded with the class `sticky-wrapper` when I scroll down via some code 'is-sticky' is added to that class.  However still does not get to me why its not adding the `whateverClass` to the logo div

Comment: I see. "is-sticky" class is added on-the-fly. Therefore, $('.logo').addClass(...) must be invoked thereafter (i.e, functionc call). jquery.ready() would not be able to do that.

Comment: Can you do an example plz

Comment: You mentioned that there is a code that adds "is-sticky" on scroll-down. Did you make that code? Or can you edit that code? If yes, just add the $('.logo').addClass(...) right after where "is-sticky" is added.

Answer (score 0):

Look for jQuery hasClass

```
if ($('#div').hasClass("is-sticky")){
    ...
}
```